# Leaflet Marker's Popup get disappear when Marker get update on the Map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have map , where I have Markers.When I click on Marker, it shows name of marker on popup using openPopup().

```
       getBindPopup: function (e) {
            var element = e;
            var latlng = [element.lat, element.lng];
            return L.popup()
                .setLatLng(latlng)
                .setContent('<a href="#" class="element-marker list-group-item" data-id="' + element.id + '">' + element.name + '</a>')
                .openPopup();
        }
```

This is the function , I am using to show Popup on marker.

I am calling this function in another function and then Markers getting update :

```
            var popup = App.elementData.getBindPopup(element);

           //below line :calling getBindPopup function
            App.map.Markers[element.id] = L.marker(latlng, element).bindPopup(popup);

           // This line will update all Markers on Map
            App.map.Count._update(App.map.Markers);
```

But after `App.map.Count._update(App.map.Markers);` popup get disappear.
 I need popup even after markers updates on the map.
Please suggest.

Thank you.